# How to locate an error message in the website dev options if the inspector isn't finding it

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have this website https://www.ultimateqa.com/complicated-page/

In it there is a field 'get latest blog posts'  I would like to automate the error message, however when I add an invalid email address i.e test123.com a error response is returned but the path to it isn't displayed in the developer options so I can't create a script and verify it.

I can see the validation message in the properties but I can't find a path for it there.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The popup which you are referring is the outcome of Constraint API's [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation#Controlling_the_text_of_constraints_violation] element.setCustomValidity() method.

You can use the "validationMessage" attribute like this:

```
    driver.get("https://www.ultimateqa.com/complicated-page/");
    WebElement inputElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"subscribe-field-blog_subscription-2\"]"));
    System.out.println(inputElement.getAttribute("validationMessage"));
    inputElement.sendKeys("test");
    System.out.println(inputElement.getAttribute("validationMessage"));
    inputElement.sendKeys("test@email.com");
    System.out.println(inputElement.getAttribute("validationMessage"));
    driver.quit();
```

Output:

```
Please fill out this field.
Please include an '@' in the email address. 'test' is missing an '@'.
```

Last print is empty which is a good email

Comment: that's great thanks, I hadn't even thought it could be an api response;-))

Comment: Glad to hear it helped you. Please accept my answer if you feel it resolved your issue.